# Using Evaporatejs with file path

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, evaporate.js

I'm trying to use Evaporatejs to upload files to AWS, but we need to use it not from the browser but from the node layer. Imagine just a javasript script that is trying to upload the "file" object that is supposed to be created from a file path.

But I don't see how this could be done since Evaooratejs uses FileAPI file object that is completely browser based.
Is there a way I could use evaporatejs to upload a file from file path and not from the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider using [aws-sdk](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/) itself?